# Error in deployment in Octopus deploy

Tags: .net, octopus-deploy, octopus

Hi I am new to Octopus deploy.

I have created a nupkg and trying to deploy it to an IIS server.

I am getting following error.

> There was a problem with your request. There must be at least one
>   enabled healthy machine to deploy to in the environment, or the
>   Project Deployment Target settings must be set to allow deployments to
>   empty environments.  Once you have corrected these problems you can
>   try again.  If the problem is related to a variable you will need to
>   update the variables for this release or recreate the release for the
>   changes to take effect.  If the problem is related to the deployment
>   process you will need to create a new release for the changes to take
>   effect.

Comment: What could be the reason of the error ?

Comment: On your deployment process steps, do the roles align with the roles associated with the deployment target? You can actually type new roles on the role selection on the deployment step, so it could be that you have typed a different role name.

Answer (score 2):

In Target Machine you have to add environment names.

Go to Infrastructure -> Deployment Targets -> any Target

then add your environment to this target. try as per below image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot you provided. it was so useful for me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

On mine my Target Role had a typo so resulted in nonsense.

Instead of being in two roles: "web-server" and "app-server" mine was in a new role called "web-server;app-server"

[image]

Which was pretty hard to spot

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger a Heath Check on the environment page and double check you have a tentacle with the role specified in your deployment step.

Comment: Target status is healthy. 
Please see following screenshot:

Comment: Is the machine tagged with a role, defined in your process actually available? For that environment?

Comment: I have added Listening Tentacle as a deployment target. 
Its health is green, so uptil this point everything is fine.

I have added a machine where I want to deploy. 
You can see the roles in the image which I have uploaded in the answer.

Answer (score -3):

Target status is healthy - please see following screenshot:

[image]